# PostgreSQL: Keep group of records depending on value in one record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a set of data like this:

[image]

I would like to construct a SELECT-statement that disregards records that share an **id** with a record that has a "NaN" in the **value**-field (plus the "NaN"-record itself).

The result should look like this:

[image]

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.value = 'NaN'
                 );
```

If your values are floats and `NaN` refers to the Postgres constant, write the logic as:

```
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.value = 'NaN'::float
```